# How i can to use django-import-export with a django-mptt?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-import-export, django-mptt

In the project i used 2 packages "django-import-export" and "django-mptt" url follow below.

django-import-export : https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

django-mqtt :  https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html

I have a problem when i import using django-import-export is not work with mqtt models. show error below

```
PARENT
Cannot assign "'Dept1'": "Dept.parent" must be a "Dept" instance.
```

[image: Error]

i think the error is cause when I import data from xlsx. the django-import-export will try to check data. due to MPTT have a node parent the second record will try to add data but not have a parent in the database.

i want to know how i can to import and export ?

thank you for expert .

Comment: can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: @MatthewHegarty thank you for answer. the error is shown on django-admin. i added in post